# Unable to send file to server from AngularJS with access token and ng-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, node.js, multer, ng-file-upload

I'm using AngularJS 1.6 to send a file to the server. The server uses Multer to read the files and I am providing a secure access token on each file uploaded.

The project uses the `ng-file-upload` which uses the `Upload.upload()` to send files. The issue pops when you have an  access token to send in conjunction with the file. I don't know what is happening, But there are no parameters sent to the server using `Upload.upload()`. I tried using `$http` and this method sends the parameters but does not upload the file to server at request.file.

The front end code looks like this

```
Upload.upload({
        url: '/upload_to_file_path',
        arrayKey: '',
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
        method: 'POST',
        file: file,
        data:
        {
          email: someData.email,
          auth_token: someData.auth_token,
        },
      })
```

When I use $http for the above it sends the token but not the file.

On the back end,

```
exports.uploads = (req, res, err) => 
{
  if (req.file == null)
  {
    //File is unable to be read here
    res.send({ msg: "filename is undefined", success: true, statusCode: 422 });
    return;
}
```

I'm losing my head over this as I'm relatively new to AngularJS. I've used Multer before so I doubt the problem is occurring on the server.

I would appreciate some help. I have been looking up for the solution for some time now, But I'm afraid I'm not able to find out what's wrong.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: How are you getting the file? Are you using the `ngf-select` directive? Show us the HTML for the `<input type="file"` element.

Comment: It seems you have two different problems. With `Upload.upload`, you get the file but you don't get parameters; with `$http` you get the parameters but not the file. Which problem do you want solved?